# Probability of getting at least one of each balls from an urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider an urn containing $4$ red balls, $4$ blue balls, $4$ yellow balls, and $4$ green balls. If 8 balls are randomly drawn from these 16 balls, what is the probability that it will contain at least one ball of each of the four colors?

**Attempted Solution:**

I think I did this right, but I just wanted to confirm.

P(at least one of each ball)

= $1$ - P(not one of each)

= $1$ - $\frac{12\choose8}{16\choose8}$ = $.9615$

**Edit:**

Actually, I think I have to choose one group of 4 to not get any selected, i.e. $4\choose1$ and then take

$1$ - $4$$\frac{12\choose8}{16\choose8}$ = $.846$

Comment: I don't think your calculation is correct, and that hunch is confirmed by a Monte Carlo simulation I just ran.  After 10^6 random trials, it showed that P(at least one of each ball) = .85, approximately. My Python code is below.

Comment: Yes, I just ran a 10^7 trial simulation, and got the same number, 0.846 (same code as below but with more iterations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use inclusion-exclusion principle:
Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_4$ denote events that there will be a red, blue, green, yellow ball in our selection respectively.

Then, by symmetry:$$P(A_1^c\cup...\cup A_4^c) = 4P(A_1^c)-6P(A_1^c\cap A_2^c) + 4P(A_1^c\cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c) - P(A_1^c\cap A_2^c \cap A_3^c \cap A_4^c) $$

Noting that $$P(A_1^c) = \frac{\binom{12}{8}}{\binom{16}{8}} \quad \quad P(A_1^c\cap A_2^c) = \frac{\binom{8}{8}}{\binom{16}{8}}$$ and the remaining terms are zeroes.

Thus $$P(A_1 \cap...\cap A_4) = 1-P(A_1^c\cup...\cup A_4^c) = \color{red}{\frac{1816}{2145}}=0.846620...$$

which is different from your proposed answer:
$$1-4\frac{\binom{12}{8}}{\binom{16}{8}} = \frac{11}{13} = 0.846154...$$

Comment: The two answers are so close that I think they might both be valid? I could be wrong and it could be coincidental.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are not equal so they cannot be both valid. But I can explain why they're close: your method of counting fails only when the 8 balls drawn are like $\{R,R,R,R,G,G,G,G\}$, and this case happens with quite small probability.

Answer (score 3):

Python code to run a Monte Carlo simulation modeling this problem:

`import numpy as np
#
urn = ['r']*4 + ['b']*4 + ['y']*4 + ['g']*4
#
numtrials = 1000000
missing_color = 0
for i in range(numtrials):
    p = np.random.choice(urn, size=8, replace=False)
    if 'r' not in p:
        missing_color += 1
    elif 'b' not in p: 
        missing_color += 1
    elif 'y' not in p: 
        missing_color += 1
    elif 'g' not in p:
        missing_color += 1
#
prob_missing = missing_color / float(numtrials)
print 'Probability of a color missing = ', prob_missing
print 'P(at least one of each ball)  = ', 1 - prob_missing`

Comment: I made a change and got very close to your .85. I think I may have got it.

Comment: I think you've got it now!   :-)

Answer (score 3):

John H, your answer is correct, although, strictly speaking, we are dealing with outcomes here and need to consider permutations but it's gonna return the same number if we swap permutations with combinations:
$$1-4\cdot\frac{P(12,8)}{P(16,8)}\approx0.85$$

There's no guessing here. The overall number of outcomes is $P(16,8)$. 
The overall number of possible unfavorable outcomes is $\;4\cdot P(12,8)$. No guessing, your answer is correct.
You can use cards for illustration. Take 16 cards, 4 clubs, 4 spades, 4 hearts, and 4 diamonds. 
A program is, of course, a nicer option.

Comment: You are subtracting too much due to double counting, e.g. clubs, clubs-spades, clubs-hearts, clubs-diamonds, then spades, **spades-clubs**,....

Answer (score 3):

**Comment** (won't fit in 'comment' format). More compact code for simulation in R. Results agree with previous simulated and combinatorial answers (+1)s.

```
urn = rep(1:4, times=4)  # a number for each color
set.seed(226);  m = 10^6
u = replicate(m, length(unique(sample(urn,8))))
mean(u == 4);  2*sd(u == 4)/sqrt(m)
## 0.846082       # aprx P(all 4 colors present among 8 balls)
## 0.0007217406   # aprx 95% margin of simulation error
table(u)/m        # aprx dist'n of nr distinct colors drawn
 u
        2        3        4 
 0.000479 0.153439 0.846082
```

With $m = 10^7$ iterations: $ 0.84661 \pm 0.00023\,$ on one run and
$0.84659 \pm  0.00023$ on another. Difficult to say for sure from these simulations,
but it seems the 4th decimal place is closer to 6 than to 2. Wish I had
a better intuitive understanding of the argument against $11/13$.

Comment: How would one do this with replacement?

Comment: `sample(urn, 8, repl=T)`

Comment: Thanks. Now knowing how to run simulations in R could come in handy in the future!

Comment: As long as you realize many mathematicians don't recognize simulations as really showing anything. Too many dishonest simulations going around. Too easy to do lots of runs and then pick an outlier that 'proves' your point. Responsible simulations show seed and estimate margin of sim error, for reproducibility . Also, gen'l combinatorial and analytic methods are of real value. (But I don't subscribe to the view that a computation is tainted if it can't be done on an abacus.) In another 25 yrs or so such discussions will be only of historical interest. Easy for me to predict; I'll be 105 then.

Comment: I would only do it as a check of my work, that the probability I calculated "properly", is correct.

Answer (score -2):

OP answer and method is not correct.

still does not count correctly.

this can be easily seen if draws 4 thru 13 are done (the distribution)

(left to the reader of course)

-Inclusion-exclusion method gets it right-

I used this:

(C(16,8)^-1) * sum((-1)^k * C(4,k) * C(4*(4-k),8)) , k=0 to 3

in Wolfram Alpha

returns
1816/2145

or
≈0.84662

pisco125 answer exactly

Sally

added:
using brute force counting in Excel and using some R code (not shown)

I get 85 unique draw results (combinations)
where 31 have at least 1 (complete set) of each color

adding the number of ways for each unique combination...

that fraction is
10896/12870

[Excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrHE0.png)

that reduces to 1816/2145
as before